# Elastic search in Docker disable ssl for local development

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-docker

I am using default yml file provided by elastic search but when i disable SSL docker containers wont start. And i want to enable our developers to connect without having to download and trust certificates manually. Compose is provided below.

```yaml
version: "2.2"

services:
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: es01\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es01\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          "  - name: es02\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es02\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          "  - name: es03\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es03\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]" ]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'"
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  es02:
    depends_on:
      - es01
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'"
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  es03:
    depends_on:
      - es02
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es03/es03.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es03/es03.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'"
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      es02:
        condition: service_healthy
      es03:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - ENTERPRISESEARCH_HOST=http://enterprisesearch:${ENTERPRISE_SEARCH_PORT}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'"
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/current/docker.html
  enterprisesearch:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      kibana:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/enterprise-search/enterprise-search:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/enterprise-search/config/certs
      - enterprisesearchdata:/usr/share/enterprise-search/config
    ports:
      - ${ENTERPRISE_SEARCH_PORT}:3002
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=enterprisesearch
      - secret_management.encryption_keys=[${ENCRYPTION_KEYS}]
      - allow_es_settings_modification=true
      - elasticsearch.host=https://es01:9200
      - elasticsearch.username=elastic
      - elasticsearch.password=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - elasticsearch.ssl.enabled=true
      - elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority=/usr/share/enterprise-search/config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - kibana.external_url=http://kibana:5601
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:3002 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'"
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

volumes:
  certs:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
  esdata03:
    driver: local
  enterprisesearchdata:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

I have tried disableing
xpack.security.enabled=true
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true

But none of these worked

Answer (score 0):

One of the other option you have, is to let the default ssl configuration, which is a better choice in my opinion as it's closer to what you will see in production.

But then, you can indeed download the generated certificates or ignore them.

Have a look at this code:

```
static private ElasticsearchClient getClient(String elasticsearchServiceAddress, byte[] certificate) {
        logger.debug("Trying to connect to {} {}.", elasticsearchServiceAddress,
                certificate == null ? "with no ssl checks": "using the provided SSL certificate");
        try {
            final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", PASSWORD));

            // Create the low-level client
            restClient = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(elasticsearchServiceAddress))
                    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(hcb -> hcb
                            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                            .setSSLContext(certificate != null ?
                                    createContextFromCaCert(certificate) : createTrustAllCertsContext())
                    ).build();

            // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
            ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

            // And create the API client
            ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

            InfoResponse info = client.info();
            logger.info("Client connected to a cluster running version {} at {}.", info.version().number(), elasticsearchServiceAddress);
            return client;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("No cluster is running yet at {}.", elasticsearchServiceAddress);
            return null;
        }
    }

private static final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
    @Override public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
    @Override public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
}};

public static SSLContext createContextFromCaCert(byte[] certificate) {
    try {
        CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Certificate trustedCa = factory.generateCertificate(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate)
        );
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        trustStore.load(null, null);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", trustedCa);
        SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, null);
        return sslContextBuilder.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static SSLContext createTrustAllCertsContext() {
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        return sslContext;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can not create the SSLContext", e);
    }
}
```

If you provide the certificate, then it's used (preferred way), if you don't you can trust the certificate like with the `-k` option of `curl`.

Source: [my java demo repo](https://github.com/dadoonet/elasticsearch-java-client-demo/blob/main/src/test/java/fr/pilato/test/elasticsearch/hlclient/EsClientIT.java)